# Feature selection for siamese network

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a regression problem for which two observations are **compared** by a siamese-like Multilayer Perceptron.

Each observation '**O**' is described by a feature vector '**X**' of a certain number '**N**' of features '**F**', such that the vector pair [*X_n, X_m*] from observations [*O_n, O_m*] is fed into the network. After a first passage through the twin channel, resulting embeddings '**E**' are pairwise-subtracted:

*X_n -> twin_ch -> E_n*

*X_m -> twin_ch -> E_m*

*dE = E_n - E_m*

The delta embedding '**dE**' is generated and then passed through the common channel:

*dE -> common_ch -> prediction*

A bidirectional similarity score '**S**' is provided back. *S* can be either positive or negative and it's a computed from *O* pairs.

I would like to know any method or rationale behind the choice of an **optimal subset** of features in order to reduce the dimensionality of *X*.
I guess that the problem here is to find the best feature which's pair [*F_i_n, F_i_m*] is optimally contributing in predicting the relative score.

I've tried to use correlation coefficients directly between each feature and the observations array:

*R_i = pearson_correlation(F_i, O)*

but a part from the poor results, I think it really misses the 'pair' concept.
Hence I also tried to operate several empiric 'relation functions' like:

[*F_i_n, F_i_m*] > *F_i_n - F_i_m = d_F_i_m*

or

[*F_i_n, F_i_m*] > *(F_i_n - F_i_m) / (F_i_n + F_I_m) = s_F_i_m*

compressing each pair in a variation metric and then using the resulting derived feature for the correlation test with *S*, but despite it's a closer rationale to what I'm looking for, it does not work as expected.

Any idea or paper?